# Problem of relation called twice on apiplatform with symfony

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have two entities: Tag, Post.
In relation Many to Many

I have an API route in GET: /api/tags/{id}

I want to return the posts associated to a tag by the tag.
But I also want to return the tags associated with the posts objects returned by the Tag.

This produces an error:

> "The total number of joined relations has exceeded the specified maximum. Raise the limit if necessary with the "api_platform.eager_loading.max_joins" configuration key (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/performance/#eager-loading), or limit the maximum serialization depth using the "enable_max_depth" option of the Symfony serializer (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-serialization-depth)."

The tag entity :

```
#[ApiResource(
normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:collection:Tag']],
collectionOperations:['get'],
paginationEnabled: false,
itemOperations: [
    'get' => [
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => [
            'read:item:Tag',
            'read:collection:Tag'
            ]]
        ],
]
)]

class Tag
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
#[Groups(['read:collection:Post', 'read:item:Category', 'read:collection:Tag'])]
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
#[Groups(['read:collection:Post', 'read:item:Category', 'read:collection:Tag'])]
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Post::class, mappedBy="tags")
 */
#[Groups(['read:item:Tag'])]
private $posts;
```

The tag field in the Post entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Tag::class, inversedBy="posts")
 */
#[Groups(['read:collection:Post', 'read:item:Category','read:item:Tag'])]
private $tags;
```

I tried limiting the maximum serialization depth using the "enable_max_depth" option as indicated in the error message, it does not work.

Comment: The second link inside the error has the solution. Set #[MaxDepth(1)] and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this problem for a many-to-many relationship when the same serialization group is used for both the entity's relationship property as well as the property that relates back from the associated entity.

In your case, I think you need to remove the `read:item:Tag` group from the `$tags` property on the `Post` entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Tag::class, inversedBy="posts")
 */
#[Groups(['read:collection:Post', 'read:item:Category'])]
private $tags;
```

I realize this may affect how data is retrieved from the `posts` endpoint, but it seems to be necessary for relationships in order to avoid recursion. Group infrastructure can get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
#[ApiResource(forceEager: false)]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).